# How to add Web API authentication filter on Controller?

Tags: c#, authentication, filter, asp.net-web-api2

I implemented web api 2, authentication filter, based in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters.

The filter works, but I can't apply in on Controller? I can only apply it globally like this;

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthenticationFilter()); // Global level
```

MyAuthenticationFilter implementation

```
using Test1.Web.Areas.Api.Models;
using Test1.Web.Areas.Api.Provisioning;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;


public class MyAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private static CustomerService = new CustomerService();
    public bool AllowMultiple => true;

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // 1. Look for credentials in the request.
        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        // 2. If there are no credentials, do nothing.
        if (authorization == null)
        {
            this.SetContextErrorResult(context);
            return;
        }

        string apiKey = authorization.Scheme;

        // 3. If there are credentials, check Schema exists. Schema has tapiKey value.
        // Authorization: apiKey
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKey))
        {
            this.SetContextErrorResult(context);
            return;
        }

        // 4. Validate tenant. Here we could use caching
        CustomerModel customer = CustomerService.Find(apiKey);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            this.SetContextErrorResult(context);
            return;
        }

        // 5. Credentials ok, set principal
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(apiKey), new string[] { });
        context.Principal = principal;
        return;
    }

    public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // currently we don't need authentication challenge
        return;
    }

    private void SetContextErrorResult(HttpAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailedResponse();
    }
}




public class AuthenticationFailedResponse : IHttpActionResult
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ApiErrorModel()
            {
                Message = "Authentication failed",
                Description = "Missing or incorrect credentials"
            }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to apply it to the controller class? Are you using the [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: Yes, but I though that `[MyAuthentication]` would work. I tried with `[Authorize]` but it does applies some other authentcation, built in.

Comment: refer this : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authorization-filters-in-asp-net-web-api-2-and-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the solution:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAuthenticationFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
```

Upper code has to be added to MyAuthentication. And now we can use it on Controller:

```
[ApiExceptionFilter]
[RoutePrefix("api/provisioning/v0")]
[MyAuthenticationFilter]
public class ProvisioningController : ApiController
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove following code from webconfig

```
config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthenticationFilter()); // Global level
```

Then add attrbute on controller. And first make sure you have added namespace of that auhthenticationfilter. and extend your class with ActionFilterAttribute and override method onactionexcecution.